# Is it possible to make HP wireless indicator light signal work with linux?

Tags: linux, hp-pavilion

I have an [HP Pavilion g6-1a52nr](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02729697), wireless indicator works on windows but not on linux, I tried many linux distros, wireless indicator doesn't work with any, currently using crunchbang 11 64 bit which is a debian distro.

This is my keyboard

[image]

And this is my wireless indicator.

[image]

On windows, if you switch it on, the light is white, switch it off, the light is red. On Linux, it works but the light stays red no matter what, is there a way to change the light to white when turned on?

Comment: Your laptop is a g6-????  Need the full device model number.

Comment: @Colyn1337 yes, hp pavilion g6, but the second picture is not right, i actually have `insert`  button next to the wireless indicator, but i didn't find a better picture

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood.  Your device is not just a G6, it's a G6-XXXXXX (such as g6-2311nr).  What is the full device model number of your laptop?

Comment: @Colyn1337 HP Pavilion g6-1a52nr sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A feature like that needs a driver for the OS to communicate with the firmware.  HP has decided NOT to make drivers for the Linux OS based on your hardware.  You can confirm that on this link specific to your hardware:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&lc=en&product=5078476

You can review the HP linux repository for other drivers and software here:

http://downloads.linux.hp.com/

I wasn't able to find 3rd party custom drivers for what you want to do.  But that doesn't mean they aren't out there, so someone else may post them.  In the event you do find drivers, here are some things you need to know.  Drivers for RedHat and SlackWare are not likely to work for you (those distro's are RPM based).  When you update your OS, you'll likely need to reinstall the 3rd party drivers after each update, so don't trash them when you're done installing.

Comment: OK I'll post an update in case I find something, thanks